# Mongodb aggregate query in nested array in nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I am trying to aggregate on a nested array which is on nested object, however, I am not able to get correct result.

This is what my schema looks like;

```
mongoose.Schema({
    parity: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    dataSet: {
        oneHour:[{
            open: Number,
            high: Number,
            low: Number,
            close: Number,
            date: Date,
            btcVolume: Number,
            _id: false
        }],
        oneDay:[{
            open: Number,
            high: Number,
            low: Number,
            close: Number,
            date: Date,
            btcVolume: Number,
            _id: false
        }],
        _id: false
    },
    _id: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

And this is the aggregation query I am using to get the latest record from collection

```
db.stockentities.aggregate( {$match : {parity: "BTC-AMP"}}, {$project: {"dataSet.oneHour": 1}},  {$unwind: "$dataSet.oneHour"}, {$sort: {'date': -1}}, {$limit: 1} ).pretty()
```

Instead I am getting the first element. (Also tried without project pipeline)

```
{
    "_id" : "BTC-AMP",
    "dataSet" : {
        "oneHour" : {
            "open" : 0.00004583,
            "high" : 0.00004631,
            "low" : 0.00004566,
            "close" : 0.00004594,
            "btcVolume" : 1.39491494,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-31T01:00:00Z")
        }
    }
}
```

And as far as I know the schema of the result should be look like;

```
{
    "_id" : "BTC-AMP",
        "oneHour" : {
            "open" : 0.00004583,
            "high" : 0.00004631,
            "low" : 0.00004566,
            "close" : 0.00004594,
            "btcVolume" : 1.39491494,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-31T01:00:00Z")
        }
}
```

So, I know there is something wrong with my aggregation query. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to invert project and unwind operator order

Comment: @Graciano hey I just saw your comment after publishing my answer. Thanks you are correct. just additionally I need to correct path for `sort` operator which should be like `oneHour.date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Need to give correct path to `sort` and swap the order of unwind and project pipelines.

```
db.stockentities.aggregate( {$match : {parity: "BTC-AMP"}}, {$unwind: "$dataSet.oneHour"} ,{$project: {"oneHour": "$dataSet.oneHour"}}, {$sort: {"oneHour.date": -1}}, {$limit: 1} ).pretty()
```

Gives

```
{
    "_id" : "BTC-AMP",
    "oneHour" : {
        "open" : 0.00003212,
        "high" : 0.00003335,
        "low" : 0.0000321,
        "close" : 0.00003301,
        "btcVolume" : 5.46422374,
        "date" : ISODate("2018-03-31T23:00:00Z")
    }
}
```